# Which end of a chocolate cornet is the head?

Tags: lucky-star

[image: Chocolate Cornet]

Some say it looks like a seashell.  Some say it looks like a caterpillar.  The real question, **which end is the head**?  Was it ever decided among the cast of Lucky Star?

Comment: Perhaps consider modifying your scope to ask if this dilemma was ever resolved amongst the cast. Right now it's a bit off-topic, since you're just talking about a pastry item that just happened to appear in an anime.

Comment: If the question is asking for an in-universe solution to the dilemma, it is on topic here. If you're asking for the official last word on chocolate cornet end terminology, that's not something we're equipped to answer.

Comment: Per @Krazer's suggestion, I've updated the question.

Comment: I think that the head it the thinner part because it is easier to bite the it leaves the sides of the bite which you bite into next and keep going till it is finished. That is it but make sure to lick the chocolate after eat bite!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Konata, about 2 years later:

[image: Which end?]

The head is the big end.